# No permitir " ' " (apóstrofo) al principio de la palabra

Tags: javascript, regex

Estoy haciendo una expresión Regular en Javascript para procesar apellidos.

Me han pedido que sea válido:

- Uno o más apellidos
- caracteres alfabeticos (con acentos) , ñ  y apóstrofo.
- el apostrofo puede ir al final de un apellido (Di' Stefan) o en medio (O'Brian) pero no al principio (<strike>'OBrian</strike> ,   <strike>O 'Brian</strike> )
- dos apellidos pueden ir separados por guiones (Menendez Martin-Vega)

**EDIT**

- El último apellido tampoco puede acabar en apostrofo ni en guión. Ej: (Menendez- , Fernandez', Martin - , ...)

Hice un regex que en el debugger online funciona.

```
([a-z\u00E0-\u00FC]+[']?[a-z\u00E0-\u00FC]?[\s-]*)+$
```

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/O_udbfU66hhYFdGM)

Pero implementandolo en javascript no falla ante apostrofos al principio:

```js
var str = "'Obrian o";
    var patt = new RegExp(/([a-z\u00E0-\u00FC]+[']?[a-z\u00E0-\u00FC]?[\s-]*)+$/i );
    console.log(patt.test(str));
```

**¿Cual es la diferencia entre el debugger y mi función?** ¿Cómo puedo lograr los puntos requeridos?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simplemente te faltaba un `^` al comienzo del patrón para decirle que empiece a hacer la comprobación desde él. En caso contrario empezará en cualquier posición a realizar las comprobaciones, por lo que el patrón se cumple perfectamente justo tras el apostrofe, cosa que no es lo que quieres:

```js
var cadenas = [
  "'Obrian o",
  "O'brian o",
  "O'brian o'",
  "O'brian oo",
  "O'brian 'o",
  "O'brian '",
  "O'brian o-",
  "Di' Stefan",
  "Di'",
  "O'BrianDi'",
  "O'Brian Di'",
  "Menendez Martin-Vega",
  "Menendez-",
  "Paco Menendez-",
  "Paco -Pelayo",
  "Paco Menendez-Pelayo",
  "Paco Menendez-Pelayo-Torres",
  "Paco Menendez Pelayo",
  "Paco Menendez-Pelayo Torres",
  "Paco Menendez Pelayo Torres",
  "Nombre Fernandez'",
  "Martin -",
];
var patt = new RegExp(
  /^([ -]([a-z][a-z']+|[a-z]+))*([ -]([a-z][a-z']+[a-z]|[a-z]+))$/i
);
for (i in cadenas) {
  var resultado = patt.test(" " + cadenas[i].trim());
  var parrafo = document.createElement("p");
  parrafo.className = resultado;
  var texto = document.createTextNode(
    cadenas[i] + ": " + resultado
  );
  parrafo.appendChild(texto);
  document.body.appendChild(parrafo);
}
```

```css
.true {
  color: green;
}
.false {
  color: red;
}
p {
  margin: 0px;
}
```

Ahora el patrón es más complejo y separado en dos partes:

- Comprobación de los primeros apellidos.
- Comprobación del último apellido.

Una mejora, para mejorar la depuración y facilitar cualquier modificación:

```js
function comprobacion(apellidos) {
  /* Patrón para todos los apellidos menos el último */
  var pat_ini = new RegExp(
    /^([a-z][a-z']+)$/i
  );
  /* Patrón para el último apellido */
  var pat_fin = new RegExp(
    /^([a-z][a-z']+[a-z]|[a-z]+)$/i
  );
  var partes = apellidos.split(/[ -]/);
  /* Comprobamos todos los apellidos menos el último */
  for (var i = 0; i < partes.length - 1; i++) {
    /* Si no coincide, informamos de ello */
    if (pat_ini.test(partes[i]) === false) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  /* Devolvemos la comprobación del último apellido */
  return pat_fin.test(partes[i]);
}

var cadenas = [
  "'Obrian o",
  "O'brian o",
  "O'brian o'",
  "O'brian oo",
  "O'brian 'o",
  "O'brian '",
  "O'brian o-",
  "Di' Stefan",
  "Di'",
  "O'BrianDi'",
  "O'Brian Di'",
  "Menendez Martin-Vega",
  "Menendez-",
  "Paco Menendez-",
  "Paco -Pelayo",
  "Paco Menendez-Pelayo",
  "Paco Menendez-Pelayo-Torres",
  "Paco Menendez Pelayo",
  "Paco Menendez-Pelayo Torres",
  "Paco Menendez Pelayo Torres",
  "Nombre Fernandez'",
  "Martin -",
];
/* Comprobamos cada una de las cadenas del test */
for (i in cadenas) {
  var resultado = comprobacion(cadenas[i]);
  var parrafo = document.createElement("p");
  parrafo.className = resultado;
  var texto = document.createTextNode(
    cadenas[i] + ": " + resultado
  );
  parrafo.appendChild(texto);
  document.body.appendChild(parrafo);
}
```

```css
.true {
  color: green;
}
.false {
  color: red;
}
p {
  margin: 0px;
}
```

Otro método en el que, para simplificar la expresión regular, comprobamos por partes cada uno de los apellidos. Fíjate en el detalle de que, en caso de tener únicamente un apellido, el bucle que comprueba el patrón `pat_ini` nunca se ejecutará.