# ¿Cómo validar un nombre con expresiones regulares?

Tags: jquery, regex

Intento validar nombres pero no se si sea adecuado usar esta expresion

```
[A-ZÄËÏÖÜÁÉÍÓÚÂÊÎÔÛÀÈÌÒÙ]
[a-zäÄëËïÏöÖüÜáéíóúáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚÂÊÎÔÛâêîôûàèìòùÀÈÌÒÙ]
+(\s)*
[a-zäÄëËïÏöÖüÜáéíóúáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚÂÊÎÔÛâêîôûàèìòùÀÈÌÒÙ]+
```

Lo que quiero validar es por ejemplo:

- Maria de la Cruz
- José Antonio

En mi expresion regular cuando llego en la parte (\s)* luego quiero volver a repetir el mismo proceso sin escribir lo primero, no se si me entiendan. Un ejemplo de lo que quiero hacer seria algo asi:

```
[A-ZÄËÏÖÜÁÉÍÓÚÂÊÎÔÛÀÈÌÒÙ]
[a-zäÄëËïÏöÖüÜáéíóúáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚÂÊÎÔÛâêîôûàèìòùÀÈÌÒÙ]
+(\s)*
([a-zäÄëËïÏöÖüÜáéíóúáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚÂÊÎÔÛâêîôûàèìòùÀÈÌÒÙ]
+(\s)*)*
([a-zäÄëËïÏöÖüÜáéíóúáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚÂÊÎÔÛâêîôûàèìòùÀÈÌÒÙ]
+(\s)*)*
```

Comment: ¿en que lenguaje?

Comment: estoy usando jquery

Comment: Pregunta relacionada: Comprobacion de nombre y apellido en JS   https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/47358/no-permitir-ap%C3%B3strofo-al-principio-de-la-palabra

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mi respuesta es en base a la cuestión más general de tu pregunta:

> volver a repetir el mismo proceso sin escribir lo primero

Cuando se desea repetir la misma expresión/bloque con algún separador entre los trozos, se suele utilizar lo siguiente:

```
{PATRON}(?:{SEPARADOR}{PATRON})+
```

Donde:

```
{PATRON}     Es la expresión que se repite. Por ejemplo [a-z]
  (?:        Inicio de grupo
{SEPARADOR}  El separador que utilizarás entre los patrones. Por ejemplo \s+
{PATRON}
  )          Fin de grupo
  +          Una o más veces (se pueden utilizar otros cuantificadores 
             dependiendo de lo que se necesite)
```

Por ejemplo, en tu caso podría haber sido algo así (será un poco diferente porque quieres la primera en mayúsculas)

```
[A-ZÄËÏÖÜÁÉÍÓÚÂÊÎÔÛÀÈÌÒÙ][a-zäÄëËïÏöÖüÜáéíóúáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚÂÊÎÔÛâêîôûàèìòùÀÈÌÒÙ]+(?:\s+[a-zäÄëËïÏöÖüÜáéíóúáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚÂÊÎÔÛâêîôûàèìòùÀÈÌÒÙ]+)+
```

Donde:

```
PATRON    => [a-zäÄëËïÏöÖüÜáéíóúáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚÂÊÎÔÛâêîôûàèìòùÀÈÌÒÙ]+
SEPARADOR => \s+
```

Además, probablemente sea buena idea agrupar todo ello entre inicio y fin de línea `^$` para evitar encontrar "Uan perez" en "jUan perez"

```
^(?:[A-ZÄËÏÖÜÁÉÍÓÚÂÊÎÔÛÀÈÌÒÙ][a-zäÄëËïÏöÖüÜáéíóúáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚÂÊÎÔÛâêîôûàèìòùÀÈÌÒÙ]+(?:\s+[a-zäÄëËïÏöÖüÜáéíóúáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚÂÊÎÔÛâêîôûàèìòùÀÈÌÒÙ]+)+)$
```

---

**Alternativa:**

Como verás, aunque el método anterior es el más común, repite la expresión (solo) una vez.

Hay otras alternativas para no repetir la expresión, como la que te presento a continuación, aunque tiene el inconveniente de que no tendrás control sobre el número de repeticiones (cantidad de nombres y apellidos). Igualmente la dejo como curiosidad o por si te puede ser de utilidad.

Consistiría en:

```
^(?!.*{SEPARADOR}(?:{SEPARADOR}|$))[{CARACTERES_ADMITIDOS}{SEPARADOR}]+$
```

Así pues, para el caso de nombres que empiecen en mayúsculas quedaría algo así (esta vez, por simplificar utilizaré SEPARADOR = espacio y Caracteres admitidos = `a-z`)

[`^(?!.* (?: |$))[A-Z][a-z ]+$`](https://regex101.com/r/9gEO3n/5/)

Si te da igual que haya dos espacios seguidos, esto sería más sencillo

```
^(?!.*{SEPARADOR}$)[{CARACTERES_ADMITIDS}{SEPARADOR}]+$
```

Ejemplo: [`^(?!.* $)[A-Z][a-z ]+$`](https://regex101.com/r/9gEO3n/6/)

---

**Alternativa con variables:**

Por supuesto, recuerda que en la gran mayoría de lenguajes de programación, puedes guardar trozos de expresiones regulares en una variable y luego utilizar las variables dentro de la expresión regular, de forma que puedas repetir los mismos trozos sin esfuerzo.